# JSON parse Android - object in object

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-json

How to parse this json? I want get data from title, field_place and brothers fields.

```
{
"events": [
{
  "event": {
    "title": "BITUMIX Martyna Jastrz\u0119bska",
    "field_place": "Nowe Miejsce Al Jerozolimskie 51 lok.2",
    "field_zdjecie": "http:\/\/wybierzkulture.waw.pl\/sites\/default\/files\/styles\/post\/public\/martyna_jastrzebska_bitumix_2.jpg?itok=nd2O5U5z"
  }
},
{
  "event": {
    "title": "Wiecz\u00f3r Komedii Improwizowanej - D\u017cem Impro!",
    "field_place": "",
    "field_zdjecie": "http:\/\/wybierzkulture.waw.pl\/sites\/default\/files\/styles\/post\/public\/dzem_17_maja.jpg?itok=bfgDYxKq"
  }
}, 
...
```

I tried:

```
JSONObject itemm = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
JSONObject oneObject = itemm.getJSONObject("event");
String title = oneObject.getString("title");
String field_place = oneObject.getString("field_place");
```

... but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does `it doesn't work` _mean_?

Comment: Also, have you looked at what JSON is? What the JSON format supports?

Comment: It mean, Android shows error:
System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for title

Comment: And what does that tell you? Given what you've shown us, it seems you have an `event` without a `title`.

Comment: And why not use Gson or Jackson instead?

Comment: JSON is generated by Drupal Module, so every event should have a title. Full JSON is here: http://pastebin.com/h4jKvACN

Comment: I suggest learning to use a debugger or `Log.d()` in order to help you figure out why you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

In a JSON string , there are two symbols that guide you through parsing :

{ - indicates a JSONObject

[ - indicates a JSONArray

When parsing a json string, you should go through this items iteratively. To understand how many JsonObjects and JsonArrays you have in your string , and from which you should start parsing, use a json-visualizer tool like [this website](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). :
[image]

**Example :** As you see, the root object is a JSONObject which consists of an JSONArray with three jsonOnjects. To parse such a structure you can use :

```
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(jsonstring);

String result = jsonObject.getString("success");
String error_number = jsonObject.getString("error_number");    
String error_message = jsonObject.getString("error_message"); 

JSON Array jsonarray = jsonobj.getJSONArray();

String[] names = new String[jsonArray.length()];    
String[] formattedNames = new String[jsonArray.length()];  

for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    names [i] = jsonObject.getString("name");
    formattedNames [i] = jsonObject.getString("formattedName");
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
JSONArray  element = jsonobj.getJSONArray("events");
              for(int i=0;i < element.length();i++){    
                    JSONObject e = element.getJSONObject(i);


                    Log.d("TESTTT22",e.getJSONObject("event").getString("title"));

              }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```